# Vmware ESXi 6.5 space reclamation from linux guest - low efficiency

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have Centos 6(7) VMs in Esxi 6.5 (Datastores VMFS6) and HPE 3PAR.

What we can do for better reclamation via `fstim`?

I have VM (250GB virtual hdd) where is on LVM ext4 90GB used – but VMDk has about 180GB after call fstrim.

I tried zeroed free space, but without effect :(.

Thank you,
Pavel

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you tried.

Comment: @Overmind - I need shrink vmdk file

Comment: Have you tried just converting it to 'Thin'? That might achieve all you wany anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should not risk manually shrinking virtual disks. ESXi is not aware of the file system layout and cannot ensure a safe shrink operation. You can remove some of the space of the OS partition inside the OS, after which you can manually edit the *.vmdk, which is the descriptor file, which contains the variables for the size of the *.-flat.vmdk and put the new value there, but this is not recommended. A simple calculation mistake or OS error can lead to data loss.

The correct method to do this is to use vCenter Converter.

- Download and install vCenter Converter on the VM you wish to re-size
- Select your Source Type: ESX Server or VirtualCenter virtual machine
- On the Source Login screen select either "This local machine" if you are running it directly on the VM, or your ESX/VC server login if you are running it remotely. In addition select the source VM if you are running it remotely
- When the Source Data screen appears it will display all the disks that the VM has assigned to it. Here is where you can resize your disks, choose to select volumes and re-size and then select one of the options and enter the new size
- Select a Destination ESX host which will typically be the same host as the source the VM is on. Then assign a name for the VM that name must be different from the source

Alternately, you could try a fstim script like [this one](https://www.circlingcycle.com.au/Unix-sources/Thin-space-reclamation.sh.txt), but there is no guarantee that something like that is bug-free.

Comment: OK, maybe here is some misunderstanding. ESXi 6.5 support guest OS UNMAP. So when vmdk is thin, is here way via fstrim in guest shrink vmdk file online by space reclamation. But when have on VM (250GB VHD) free size about 170GB I can't shrink it via space reclamation to 80GB vmdk... it is cca double.

Comment: Did you try using esxcli storage vmfs unmap ?

Comment: Yes. Tried. After fstrim disks shrinked from 250 to 180G for example. But no more.

Comment: You probably can't shrink it more because of the data layout in the OS, like I said in the answer.